# Regex to allow only certain special characters and restrict underscore

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, regex

As the Title suggests, i want to allow only - / \ (dash, forward slash, backward slash) from special characters. Which is this regex bellow doing, but it doesn't match underscore. How can I do it?

JavaScript:  `/[^\w\-\/\\]/gi`

.NET : `^[\w-\/\\]*$`

Comment: *"I want to allow only - / \"*. But you're including them in negated class?

Comment: Note that `/[^\w\-\/\\]/gi` does not match `_` because `[^\w]` does not match it. `^[\w-\/\\]*$` does match `_`. So, please explain a bit more what you need in the end.

Comment: @psy Are you trying to prevent SQL Injection or "bad" passwords by chance?

Comment: @TerryCarmen just input.replace on certain pattern

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i haven't been clear enough, but you still nailed it, good job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add an alternative in your JS regex:

```
var pattern = /(?:[^\w\/\\-]|_)/g;
               ^^^          ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KizVOo/1/). This pattern can be used to *remove* the unwanted chars in JS.

In a .NET regex, you may use a [*character class substraction*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html), and the pattern can be written as

```
var pattern = @"[^-\w\/\\-[_]]";
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5E-%5Cw%5C%2F%5C%5C-%5B_%5D%5D&i=abcABC123%60-%3D%5C%5D%5B%27%3B%2F.%2C%3C%3E%3F%3A%22%7B%7D%7C%2B_%29%28*%26%5E%25%24%23%40!&r=)

To match whole strings that only allow `-`, `/` and `\` + letters/digits, use

```
var pattern = /^(?:(?!_)[\w\/\\-])*$/;
var pattern = @"^[-\w/\\-[_]]*$";
```

See this [JS regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r8bqut/1) and the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B-%5Cw%2F%5C%5C-%5B_%5D%5D*%5Cr%3F%24&i=abcABC123%7E!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*%28%29_%2B%7C%7D%7B%22%3A%3F%3E%3C%2C.%2F%3B%27%5B%5D%5C%3D-%60%0D%0AabcABC123%0D%0AabcABC123-%2F%5C%0D%0AabcABC123-%2F%5C_&o=m).

Here, `^(?:(?!_)[\w\/\\-])*$` / `^[-\w/\\-[_]]*$` match a whole string (the `^` and `$` anchors require the full string match) that only contains word, `/`, `\` and `-` chars.

**NOTE**: In C#, `\w` by default matches much more than `\w` in JS regex. You need to use `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option to make `\w` behave the same way as in JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow only dash, forward slash and backward slash, then you could omit the `^`. It means a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

You could use `\w` to also match and underscore and add the hyphen as the first character in the character class.

`/[-\w/\\]/g`

To match the whole string you could use a quantifier `+` for the character class to match one or more times and begin `^` and end `$` of the string anchors:

`^[-\w/\\]+$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C1gWY1/1/)

```js
const regex = /^[-\w/\\]+$/g;
const strings = [
  "test2_/\\",
  "test2$_/\\"
];
strings.forEach((str) => {
  console.log(str.match(regex));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused between your aim and your code. So, is [this what you want](https://codepen.io/Rahul_V7/pen/WavBjj) ?

Pattern - `/[\\\/-]/g`